# Unable to close Word when there is an instance of Word Application running in my app

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, process, ms-word

I created a windows form that opens a word document using `Word.Application`, the code works fine and I am able to view, edit and save the document.

The problem is when I open another Microsoft Word instance (outside my app), the word instance opens on the same `WINWORD.exe` process, I mean there is only one `WINWORD.exe` process in the task manager processes no matter how many Word instances I open, thus, the word instance that is outside my app cannot be closed (using the X button, File => Close, or Alt + F4), it cannot be closed unless I close the word instance inside my app.

I do not know why it is opening on the same process that my app created, it is treating the newly opened word instance as a document of my Word Application object (however it opens in a new word window outside my app), so you cannot close the document without closing the main app object.

Here is the code that I am using to load the word application inside my form:

```
Public Sub LoadDocument(ByVal t_filename As String)
    filename = t_filename
    If wd Is Nothing Then
        wd = New Word.Application()
        End If

    Try
        wd.CommandBars.AdaptiveMenus = False
    Catch
    End Try

    If wordWnd = 0 Then
        wordWnd = FindWindow("Opusapp", wd.Caption)
    End If
    If wordWnd <> 0 Then
        SetParent(wordWnd, Me.Handle.ToInt32())

        Dim newTemplate As Object = False
        Dim docType As Object = 0
        Dim [readOnly] As Object = True
        Dim isVisible As Object = True
        Dim missing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

        Try
            If wd Is Nothing Then
                Throw New WordInstanceException()
            End If

            If wd.Documents Is Nothing Then
                Throw New DocumentInstanceException()
            End If

            If wd IsNot Nothing AndAlso wd.Documents IsNot Nothing Then
                'Dim HearingTemplet As Word.Template = wd.NormalTemplate

                Dim d As Word.Documents = wd.Documents

                document = d.Add(fileName, True, docType, isVisible)

                document.ShowGrammaticalErrors = False
                document.ShowRevisions = False
                document.ShowSpellingErrors = False

                document.Application.Visible = False
                document.Application.Options.SuggestSpellingCorrections = False
                document.Application.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = False
                document.Application.Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType = False
                document.Application.Options.CheckGrammarWithSpelling = False
                document.SaveAs(fileName)
            End If
        Catch
        End Try

        Try
            wd.ActiveWindow.DisplayRightRuler = False
            wd.ActiveWindow.DisplayScreenTips = False
            wd.ActiveWindow.DisplayVerticalRuler = False
            wd.ActiveWindow.DisplayRightRuler = False
            wd.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.DisplayRulers = False
            wd.ActiveWindow.Caption = ""

            wd.Options.SaveInterval = 0
            wd.Options.AllowFastSave = False
            wd.ActiveWindow.Document.ReadOnlyRecommended = True
            wd.ActiveWindow.Split = False
            wd.Application.DisplayRecentFiles = False
            wd.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = WdViewType.wdNormalView
            wd.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = WdViewType.wdPrintView
        Catch
        End Try
        Try
            wd.Visible = True
            wd.Activate()               
        Catch
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

**P.S:** the problem occurs no matter how many word instances I open, all of them are being opened on the same process, all of them are treated as a document of my word application, and I cannot close any of them unless I close the Word Application in my form.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to dispose the object or quit the application after your finished?

```
wd.quit()
```

see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844895.aspx

or

```
set wd = Nothing
GC.Collect()
```